# Hide links from html

Tags: javascript, html, css, xml

Suppose I have several links like

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google </a>
```

How to remove the link so that user can't use view source to see the link.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to hide the link completely from your code. You could handle links via javascript (harder to find the link?).

```
<a href="#" id="secretLink>Google</a>
<script>
   document.querySelector('#secretLink').addEventListener('click',function(){
      location.href = YOURDESTINATION;
   });
</script>
```

But i don't recommend to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Is's strictly impossible : the best way to understand it is that your browser itself needs the link ref to be able to jump to the page. If your browser can read this info, this means that you can read it somewhere, as well.